# How to have an href process in an iframe (colorbox) after running a php script?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, colorbox

What I am trying to figure out is how to have a link open in an iframe (using colorbox) after a php script has been fully processed. The reason I need to have the link load after the php script is that in php script I generate a png image from a canvas element on the page. This image is then used as the image on the subsequent page.

The issue I have been having is that if the link opens prior to the completion of imagesave script the link will not function correctly (ie the image will not appear (first time clicked) or the last image saved will appear rather then the intended image).

I am using Jquery and Colorbox on the page. The javascript passes the variables to the php which stores them in a session.

My HTML on the main page is as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".share").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
    });
</script>
    <canvas id="YourYogaMatCanvas"  width="888" height="288" >Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas><br/>
    <a href="featureshare" class="share" id="sharing" onclick="savetoserver();">Share Your Creation Now</a><br/><br/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function savetoserver() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('YourYogaMatCanvas');

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    var dataURL2 = canvas.toDataURL();

    do {
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    dataURL2 = canvas.toDataURL();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "featureimagesave.php",
          data: {
            imgBase64: dataURL,
            yogatextcolor: txtcolorsel,
            yogamatcolor: selmatcolor,
            prefile: prefile,
            name: matname,
            price: priceCalc
          },
        });
    }while (dataURL != dataURL2);
}
```

PHP featureimagesave:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // requires php5
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/users/');
    $img = $_POST['imgBase64'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $filename = uniqid();
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . $filename . '.png';

    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

    $_SESSION['file'] = $filename;
    $_SESSION['textcolor']  = $_POST['yogatextcolor'];
    $_SESSION['matcolor']  = $_POST['yogamatcolor'];
    $_SESSION['featurefile']  = $_POST['prefile'];
    $_SESSION['name']  = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['price']  = $_POST['price'];
?>
```

HTML on featureshare page the $Session variable file is used to reference the image as follows:

```
<?php  
    echo '<div id="uimage"><img id="userimage" src="images/users/'.$_SESSION['file'].'.png"> </div>';
?>
```

Any help or an idea of how to make this work would be greatly appreciated. I do have session start on every page prior to the HTML tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try something like the done function of an ajax request something like:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "featureimagesave.php",
      data: {
        imgBase64: dataURL,
        yogatextcolor: txtcolorsel,
        yogamatcolor: selmatcolor,
        prefile: prefile,
        name: matname,
        price: priceCalc
      },
  }).done(function ( data ) {
       //do your colorbox logic
  });
```

This are jQuery's promise callbacks and work I think as of jQuery 1.5, for more info you could see jquery's API http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I will give that a try, then I guess how do I prevent the link in the HTML from being processed until the AJAX has been completed? Do I have to delay the click?

Comment: I think I would set the href="#" and then I would call the colorbox from the javascript inside the done function. With something like $.colorbox({href:"thankyou.html"});